# Bold Last 8th Row of Particular Dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, html-table, dplyr

I have below mentioned data frame:

```
Type   A    B    C   D
A1     1    1    0   2
A2     2    1    1   0
A3     1    0    2   0
...
A7     1    0    1   0
Sum    5    2    4   2
```

For the above dataframe i want to bold the last row `Sum` and color it yellow.

Comment: Is this to write in a file?

Comment: @akrun No, than i will convert it into html table.

Comment: You can check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html)

Comment: @akrun Thanks for sharing that is really a very helpful, can you help me here with my issue to bold the last row only.

Comment: Sure, I will post as a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the rmarkdown file `.Rmd`, we do

````
---
title: "Markdown"
author: "akrun"
date: "February 27, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Table

```{r code1, include = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

df1 <- structure(list(Type = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A7", "Sum"), 
     A = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L), B = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L), 
     C = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L), D = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L)), 
     .Names = c("Type", "A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, -5L))


```


```{r code2, echo = FALSE }
kable(df1, "html") %>%
       kable_styling("striped", full_width = F) %>%
       row_spec(nrow(df1), bold = TRUE, color = "white", background = "yellow")

```
````

-output

[image]

---

If we need to use `tableHTML` change the r code blocks

````
---
title: "Markdown"
author: "akrun"
date: "February 27, 2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Table


```{r code1, include = FALSE, cache = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)    
library(tableHTML)

df1 <- structure(list(Type = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A7", "Sum"), 
     A = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L), B = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L), 
     C = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L), D = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L)), 
     .Names = c("Type", "A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, -5L))

```


```{r code2, echo = FALSE }

df1 %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE, widths = rep(c(100, 50), c(1, 4)), 
             second_headers = list(c(1, 2, 2), c("", "ABC", "XYZ"))) %>%
  add_css_caption(css = list(c("font-weight", "border"), c("bold", "1px solid black"))) %>%
  add_css_row(css = list(c("background-color"), "yellow"), rows = nrow(df1)+2) %>%
  add_css_caption(css = list("background-color", "lightblue"))



```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: How to do the same in my existing code which looks like this: `Table1 <- DF %>% 
    tableHTML(rownames = FALSE,
    widths = rep(100, 13),
    second_headers = list(c(1, 6, 6),
                                    c("", "ABC", "XYX")),
              caption = "ABC Stat") %>%
    add_css_caption(css = list(c("font-weight", "border"),
                               c("bold", "1px solid black"))) %>% 
    add_css_row(css = list(c("background-color"), c("lightblue")), 
                rows = 0:2) %>% 
    add_css_caption(css = list(c("background-color"), c("lightblue")))`

Comment: @Roy1245  Updated the post.  Change the `widths`  according to your original dataset

Comment: Please help me here to bold only last row with yellow background color in my existing code.

Comment: It worked but except the last line is not in bold yet.

Comment: @Roy1245  I was checking the [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html), sorry couldn't find an option there

Comment: How to bold 1, 3 and 5 row of dataframe bold and highlight background with yellow color.

Comment: @Roy1245  Please post as a new question